# JavaFX actions on elements of one window from another window

Tags: java, javafx

Please help me solve the problem. There are two fxml files and their controllers:

```
sample.fxml, its controller ControllerMain (main window of the program)
find_win.fxml, its ControllerFind controller (modal window "text search")
```

In the modal window find_win.fxml there is a TextField into which the search text is entered, and the Find button, when clicked, ControllerFind must process the click and call the search method and highlight the search text in the TextArea element of the sample.fxml window.

`<fx: include source = "sample.fxml" fx: id = "textAreaOne" />`

and the inheritance of the ControllerMain by the ControllerFind controller does not help to achieve a solution - in the first case the entire window markup is included in the modal window completely, in the second case, the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException is returned during an operation on the TextArea.

How to implement actions on elements of one window from another window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution elsewhere. Thanks to Comrade Antizam, who tried to help, but did not quite understand what I needed.

The solution described [here is](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/904122/281603) .

In short, it is necessary to create an instance of a controller-parent and a method that takes an instance of a controller-parent as a parameter in the controller-child. When a new window is opened from a controller-parent, get an instance of the controller-child and indicate to it through the created method "this".

Further, in the controller-child, it will be possible to access the elements of the parent controller.

controller-parent:

```
package sample;

public class ControllerMain {

    private ControllerFind children;  // controller-child

    //main-window
    @FXML
    public TextArea textAreaOne;
    @FXML
    public MenuItem findMenuItem;

    public void findAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            Stage stageFind = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML/find_win.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            stageFind.setTitle("Find");
            stageFind.setMinHeight(200);
            stageFind.setMinWidth(150);
            stageFind.setResizable(false);
            stageFind.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stageFind.getIcons().add(new Image("image/search.png"));
            stageFind.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            stageFind.show();

            children = loader.getController(); //getting controller of window find_win.fxml
            children.setParent(this);   //setting parent of the controller-child - this

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

controller-child:

```
package sample.Controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.Classes.DialogManager;
import sample.ControllerMain;

public class ControllerFind {

    //Window "Find"
    @FXML public TextField searchTextField;
    @FXML public Label findTextLabel;
    @FXML public Button okTextFindButton;
    @FXML public Button cancelTextFindButton;
    private String text;
    private ControllerMain controller;

    public void setParent (ControllerMain controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public ControllerFind getThis(){
        return this;
    }

    public void initialize(){
        System.out.println("psvm");
    }

    public void textFindOkButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        text = (searchTextField.getText());
        if (text.equals("")) {
            DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Error!", "Enter text what you are looking for!");
        } else {
            if (controller.textAreaOne.getText() != null && !controller.textAreaOne.getText().isEmpty()) {
                int index = controller.textAreaOne.getText().indexOf(text);
                if (index == -1) {
                    DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Result", "There isn't text what you are looking for");
                } else {
                    controller.textAreaOne.selectRange(index, index + text.length());
                }
            } else {
                DialogManager.showInfoDialog("Error", "TextArea is empty!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void textFindCancelButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Node source = (Node) actionEvent.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vis-a-vis windows communication in this situation, it's optimal to use `TextInputDialog` something like this:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        Button btn=new Button("Click");
        VBox vbox=new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(btn);
        Scene scene=new Scene(vbox, 200,200);

        btn.setOnAction(e->
        {
            TextInputDialog dialog=new TextInputDialog();
            Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent()){
                System.out.println(result.get());
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

but text highlighting is not something that can be done easy. 
You could do String search of TextArea text, compare it to result from another window then highlight it via

```
textArea.getSelectedRange(firstIndex, lastIndex);
```

firstIndex and lastIndex being indexes of textArea text for the word we are searching. Then having button on every click displaying next word occurancy inside text and highlighting it. But if you insist on highlighting every instance of word at the same time I would suggest using [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX).